# Can we get list of all anchors having data-ng-click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have one web application in asp.net with angularjs.
I want to get all anchor tags having data-ng-click.
Is this possible?If yes then how?
i tried using 
`var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");` 
but it is giving list of all anchor tags
i want only those anchor tags which have data-ng-click.
I am trying to get this list in google console.
If its working ,then i will add it in google extension .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the elements with a specific attribute use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[data-ng-click]");
```

or with angularjs:

```
angular.element("a[data-ng-click]")
```